Understanding STR to SNP imputation methods
I am struggling to find the exact step-by-step algorithm of STR to SNP imputation, but failing so far. I figured there's Beagle software, but I can't find out how it works (math behind it). My actual interest is how to get SNP data for cattle when I have STR data, and vice versa

If I understand correctly, you have STR data, and you want to rely on LD to infer linked SNP genotypes? That sounds hard, for a couple of reasons:

LD decays very quickly between STRs and SNPs (shown variously: here, here, and here). This is due to high mutation rates. That makes any process of imputation difficult.
Relatedly, parallel mutation towards the same allele is common in STRs, meaning that even if you do have matching genotypes, identity-by-state is not a good basis for inferring relationships. This can lead to long-distance apparent LD.

The Beagle docs make no mention of the terms "microsatellite" or "STR". I am not sure that the software can use multiallelic loci. It says:

Each genotype must have two phased, non-missing alleles.

If you do want to try using Beagle, perhaps by collapsing your microsatellites to biallelic populations using a mixture model or something (which I wouldn't recommend but you could do), you can readily find the math in the papers. Specifically Appendices A and B at that link has a description of the HMM approach.
I would suggest instead looking at the Payseur paper, which seems to have some recommendations for attempting this approach. That paper is now pretty old though, so take it with a grain of salt.

Thank you a lot for answering! I got it that it is pretty hard to infer SNP from given STR, and how about vice versa? What if I had SNP data and wanted to restore STR? From your explanation it sounds like is must be same difficult task?
Also, can it be that the precision of such inference would be good enough for cattle examination? My problem is connected with cows breeding, and perhaps such imputation  would work in this field?..
Thanks for the links to the papers, too!

@Helen yes, I think that is true that the converse problem is as hard if not actually harder. Note, people have done stuff like what you want to do I'm pretty sure, but you are going to suffer from significant imprecision. Maybe that's ok from your perspective! If you had really well characterized haplotypes in your pedigree (STR+SNP), which might be possible for breeding cattle stock, you could decide to just map those together after transforming STRs to biallelic, or something similar. I'd repeat that the Payseur paper probably has suggestions for what you're trying to do, old as it is.

the Payseur paper, as I understand it, seems to be more about measuring some correlation between given STR and SNP... Probably the other one (with HMM) is more suitable in my case, I'm currently trying to figure that out for myself.

As for transormation of STRs to biallelic, - could you please give me a hint of how it is done? I tried to google myself but didn't manage to find anything on this topic so far

PS I think I got it, thank you again!

@Helen The correlation in question is linkage disequilibrium, aka how much information knowing a SNP genotype gives you about nearby STR genotypes (or vice versa). Clustering of STRs to biallelic: I have never done this but I have heard it suggested. I am not sure that it's a good idea. What you could do is fit a 2-component mixture model to the distribution of STR allele lengths using R or similar. I'm not aware of any packaged tools that do this.

@Helen In any case: if you have found the answer helpful, traditionally you upvote. If it has solved your problem, traditionally you accept the answer. I am not clear whether this has been helpful or has solved your problem, though.
